# Text in wordpress widget placed as li item behaves differently with same styling

Tags: css, wordpress, widget

Live link here 
http://soloveich.com/pr6/

Image description text in widgets that are closer to the left is slightly off to the left. When i change screen width and all of the images are in one vertical line- all of their text starts behaving the same way. Checked out source code. Looks the same for all of the items from where i am.

I did override widget's

styling in my styles sheet. Though, it doesn't look like that is it. After taking that styling off the css it still shifts the same way.

I'm using Image widget by Modern Tribe. And these widgets are in ul.

And a little bit of code.

```
<div class="mainlist">
            <ul>
                    <li><?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('1grid Widgets') ) : ?>
  <?php endif; ?></li>
</div>
```

There are more li's, but the code is pretty much the same, except widget name.

and css
    .mainlist {
    overflow: hidden;
    }

```
.mainlist ul {
list-style: none;
margin-left: -35px;
max-width: 1000px;
}

.mainlist ul li {
display: inline-block;
padding-bottom: 15px;
float: left;
}


.widget_sp_image-description p {
margin-top: -35px;
margin-left: 25px;
font-family: tahoma;
font-size: 13px;
color: #414040;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the `<ul>` tag that have a negative margin of 35px, if you reset the margin all `<li>`'s will have the same padding:

`.mainlist ul {
    margin-left: 0;
}`